# htaccess change url, don't redirect

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have been doing some searching and can't seem to find the right answers.

I have webmail service setup in my domain that my users can hit (http://domain.com/webmail)

However when the user goes their URL changes to http://domain.com:2095

I would like to mask that, so the user still accesses :2095 but the URL always looks like /webmail

Possible? Hope so!

A note: I am assuming that my host (hostgator) takes care of the initial redirection (from */webmail to *:2095) because I do not have a webmail folder in my directory.

Thanks SO!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to setup a reverse proxy. You need to get rid of the redirection first, then you need to setup something like this in your htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^webmail(.*)$ http://domain.com:2095/$1 [L,P]
```

Chances are, hostgator doesn't have mod_proxy loaded, and that means you're screwed. The best you can do is create a page that uses an iframe that points to `http://domain.com:2095/`.

Comment: That was sort of my fear. The iFrame is a kludgy, but good, work around.

Thanks!